# How to construct nested numpy record arrays?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

The [numpy manual](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/neps/npy-format.html#use-cases) mentions use case for [numpy.save](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.save.html)

> Annie Analyst has been using large nested record arrays to represent
>   her statistical data.

Is it possible to have nested records array without dtype=object? If so, how?

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19201868/how-to-set-dtype-for-nested-numpy-ndarray answer your question?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, like so:

```
engine_dt = np.dtype([('volume', float), ('cylinders', int)])
car_dt = np.dtype([('color', int, 3), ('engine', engine_dt)])  # nest the dtypes

cars = np.rec.array([
    ([255, 0, 0], (1.5, 8)),
    ([255, 0, 255], (5, 24)),
], dtype=car_dt)

print(cars.engine.cylinders)
# array([ 8, 24])
```

The `np.dtype` function isn't strictly necessary here, but it's usually a good idea, and gives a small speed boost over letting `array` call it every time.

Note that `rec.array` is only necessary here to use the `.engine` notation. If you used a plain `np.array`, then you'd use `cars['engine']['cylinders']`

Comment: The data for `cars` has to be properly nested as you (right mix of [] and ()).  That can be a source of errors.  But when loading from a `csv` `genfromtxt` can use a 'flat' list of columns, as long as there's enough data.

Comment: Just checked: `genfromtxt` first creates an array with a flattened version of the `dtype`, and then returns a view with the nested dtype.

Comment: Can this be done with lists of different lengths? E.g. how would it look like if I want to add a field ``photo`` to the ``car_dt`` which is a 2-dimensional array of unknown size and type int? (let's use a black/white image for simplicity)

Comment: No, numpy has no mechanism for subarrays of "unknown size". You'll have to use an `object` field to store that array

Answer (score -2):

You can construct nested arrays the same way you construct nested lists:

```
nested_list = [['a',1],['b',2],['c',3]]

import numpy as np
nested_array = np.array(nested_list)
```